# Non-synchronized method that calls synchronized methods only

Tags: java, synchronization

Is it safe to make a non-synchronized method if it only calls synchronized methods?

Say we have:

```
public class SomeClass{
    public synchronized void A(){
        //Some code
    }
    public synchronized void B(){
        //Some code
    }
    public synchronized void C(){
        A();
        B();
    }
}
```

Should C() be synchronized or not?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "safe" and how you use those. In this case however, it's obvious that `C` has to be synchronized, since all methods are public (And a caller can do `B(); A();` in parallel with `C()`)

Answer (score 5):

That depends. Could there be problems if something happens between the calls to `A` and `B`? If so, then `C` should be synchronized.

```
public class SomeClass{
    private int i;
    public synchronized void A(){
        i += 1;
    }
    public synchronized void B(){
        print i; // uses something modified by A
    }
    public void C(){ // unsynchronized so...
        A();
        // ...i could be changed here by another thread, affecting what B prints
        B();
    }
}
```

If there is no critical section between `A` and `B`, then `C` doesn't need to be synchronized.

```
public class SomeClass{
    private int i;
    public synchronized void A(){
        i += 1;
    }
    public synchronized void B(){
        print "B"; // unrelated to what A does
    }
    public void C(){
        A();
        // i could be changed here, but won't affect B
        B();
    }
}
```